# How to display PDF URL file in app and it opens or views next page of PDF file like iBook

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

How to display PDF URL file in app and it opens or views next page of PDF file like iBook? I open the PDF URL on WebView but I'm not able to open the page like a book.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**URL:**

```
func loadFromUrl(){
    let url =  NSURL(string:"https://www.yourpdfFileUrl.pdf")

    myWebView?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!))
}
```

**Local:**

```
func loadFromLocal()
{
    let pdfPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myPdfFile", ofType: "pdf")!)
    myWebView?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: pdfPath))


}
```

Or

Follow this [link](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13PDFKit)

Comment: I am able to open pdf file link but need open like page-turning interface similar to Apple's iBooks of PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Opening `.pdf` in `WebView` will work but it will not have page curl effect like iBooks. For that you need to do this.

> 1. To achieve iBooks like effect you need to render pdf on view.
> 2. And you have to use UIPageViewController with curl animation.

**If your using iOS 11.0 and onwards you can do it using newly available [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit).**